# Python date - iterative column names

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, iteration

I am creating column names as strings. The names represent years and months starting at the beginning date of my data (the dataset is essentially a matrix with dates as the index and "date" strings as the col names)

However, my code is not correct:

```
    #date range index
    output_frame_index = pd.date_range(min_date,periods = (months_of_data + future_prtiods), freq = 'M' ) 

    #column names
    cols = []
    for i in range(months_of_data+1):
        year = min_date.year + math.floor(i/12)
        month = ( min_date.month + i)  % 12
        if not month: month = 12
        col_label = str(year) + ' ' + str(month)
        cols.append(col_label)

    # create empty output frame   
    output_frame = pd.DataFrame(index = output_frame_index, columns = cols)

    return output_frame
```

The above correctly starts with "2011 3" as the first column but after "2011 12" iterates through "2011 1", "2011 2", 2012 3".

Thank you in advance.

[edit]

Ended up implementing:

```
        cols = [x.date().strftime('%Y_%m') for x in pd.date_range(min_date,periods=months_of_data,freq='M')]
```

Based on awesome answer below. Thank you.

Comment: I always use `01`,`02`, `03` to get correct order when names are somehow sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
months_of_data = 24
min_date = '2018-01-01'

cols = (pd.date_range(min_date, periods=months_of_data, freq='M')
        .strftime('%Y %-m')  # '%Y %m' for 2018 01, 2018 02, ...
        .tolist())
>>> cols
['2018 1',
 '2018 2',
 '2018 3',
 '2018 4',
 '2018 5',
 '2018 6',
 '2018 7',
 '2018 8',
 '2018 9',
 '2018 10',
 '2018 11',
 '2018 12',
 '2019 1',
 '2019 2',
 '2019 3',
 '2019 4',
 '2019 5',
 '2019 6',
 '2019 7',
 '2019 8',
 '2019 9',
 '2019 10',
 '2019 11',
 '2019 12']
```